# How big is the sessions hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, session, hash

From a [blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) by Justin Weiss:

> You can only store about 4kb of data in a cookie.

Cookies live in the sessions hash; however, this doesn't address the hash itself. Reading the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) I'm also not able to find the answer.

Very simple question:

- What is the largest array of integers that can fit in the sessions hash?

For example, given an array `max_array` that is the largest array that can fit in the sessions hash what would `max_array.length` be?

```
sessions[:max_array] = max_array # doesn't fail
p max_array.length #=> ?
```

Comment: Not the hash, the cookie itself is limited to 4kb. The hash has to be serialized, encrypted, and then (AFAIK) Base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How big is the hash then?